# C# sharing content on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

First thing first, I never used SDK before and I don't know what does `token` mean. I am searching for the most simple solution, if possible without SDK, without token, without FB App.

I have a button in my C# application and when the user clicks on it I want a popup window where the user can login to Facebook or if he is logged in he can push the share button in order to share the predefined content.

While searching on the internet I found this code:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("my_access_token");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
parameters.name = "Article Title";
parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
parameters.actions = new {
    name = "View on Zombo",
    link = "http://www.zombo.com",
};
parameters.privacy = new {
    value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
};
parameters.targeting = new {
    countries = "US",
    regions = "6,53",
    locales = "6",
};
dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

But this example uses Facebook SDK and it needs token. I want a simple solution, without SDK, without FB APP. I want a simple popup with predefined text.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

An access token is an opaque string that identifies a user, app, or page and can be used by the app to make graph API calls.

> Access Tokens identifies an app ,user or page

Without creating an app from facebook and getting a token you cannot proceed in this case(c# application).